# jmeter: resolve user defined variable on Directory Listing plugin

Tags: jmeter

I've set `BUNDLE_DIRECTORY` user defined variable as:

[image]

Nevertheless, when I'm using it on `Directory Listing Data Source` it's not able to resolve it:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [User Defined Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) which is set on the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level will be available in the runtime, i.e. when you start your JMeter test.

In order to see the variable value you can add [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/):

[image]

If you want to use "Test Directory Listing" it has to be a [JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#introduction)